# How to regroup an array with X elements?

Tags: php

I have an array with X (let's say 40) elements. Now I need to regroup the X elements become Y (let's say 8) sub-arrays. Each sub-array consists of Z (let's say 5) elements. How can I do this?

```
$numbers = array('1','2',...,'40'); //original array
$numbers = array(array('1','2','3','4','5'), array('6','7','8','9','10'), ...);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `array_chunk` is in the manual :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`array_chunk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) does this:

```
$numbers = array_chunk($numbers, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the numbers, you can loop through the original array, and in the loop, take (5) elements, and put them into a new array, which you then shove into the output.